# Queryset ordered by must frequent values

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to order a simple queryset by the must frequent value in a column. For exemple, I have those models:

```py
class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(verbose_name='Keyword', null=False, blank=False, max_length=20)


class BigText(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(verbose_name='Big Text', null=False, blank=False, max_length=1000)


class BigTextKeyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword, verbose_name='Keyword', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bigtext = models.ForeignKey(BigText, verbose_name='Big Text', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then,  I'm searching for the keywords passed on query params and returning the BigTextKeywords result found like this:

```py
class BigTextKeywordViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = BigTextKeyword.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BigTextKeywordSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        keyword_filter = Q()
        search_content = self.request.query_params.get('search_content', '')

        for term in search_content.split(' '):
            keyword_filter |= Q(keyword__icontains=term)

        keywords = Keyword.objects.filter(keyword_filter)
        
        result = self.queryset.filter(keyword__in=keywords)
        return result
```

I want to order the result by the must frequent `bigtext` field. For example, if a `bigtext` occurs 3 times on the result, it should appears first than a `bigtext` that occurs 2 times. With the similar result below:

| keyword_id | bigtext_id |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 5 |
| 19 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 15 | 10 |
| 13 | 10 |
| 87 | 2 |
| 19 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's annotate() method to add a computed field to each BigTextKeyword object that represents the frequency count of its associated BigText. Then, you can use the order_by() method to sort the queryset in descending order based on this computed field.

Here’s an example:

```py
from django.db.models import Count

class BigTextKeywordViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = BigTextKeyword.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BigTextKeywordSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        keyword_filter = Q()
        search_content = self.request.query_params.get('search_content', '')

        for term in search_content.split(' '):
            keyword_filter |= Q(keyword__icontains=term)

        keywords = Keyword.objects.filter(keyword_filter)

        # Use annotate to add a computed field for the frequency count of each BigText
        result = self.queryset.filter(keyword__in=keywords).annotate(
            bigtext_count=Count('bigtext')
        )

        # Order the results based on the frequency count in descending order
        result = result.order_by('-bigtext_count')

        return result
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it helped me a lot. I got your suggestion and I improved that with this: ```result = self.queryset.filter(keyword__in=keywords).values('bigtext').annotate( bigtext_count=Count('bigtext'))```, then it worked good.